# Two MappedSuperClass object error: This class does not define an IdClass

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I've an object which extends from an super class -this class extends from another one-

After when I create a `JpaRepository` with this class

```
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, Long>
```

spring throws this exception:

```
This class [com.example.Test] does not define an IdClass
```

My classes are like this below;

```
@Entity
public class Test extends BaseTest {

}

@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseTest extends BaseClass {
    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private A test;
}

@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseClass {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}
```

Comment: if you want a composite primary key, there is a different way to do that, you can not otherwise just annotate 2 fields with `@Id`

Comment: Compare Your code [with this example](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/01/jpa-idclass-example)